# EWS ContainmentMode Substring searches only for prefix

Tags: exchangewebservices

I am using EWS to search for contacts via FindItem.
I added a Restriction to filter the results, and I am using Contains with ContainmentMode = Substring.

Contacts are being returned only when filtering with prefixes, but when using middle parts of their name/email nothing gets returned.

for example if user name is user3, then if i filter with "use"/"user" the contact returns, but if i use "ser"/"ser3" i get nothing.

can anyone help?
thanks a lot